# Spring boot не отдается страница

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, spring-boot, mustache

Начинаю разбираться со спрингом. Не работает самый банальный пример, со статьи на хабре.

**IndexController.java**

```
@Controller
public class IndexController {
    @GetMapping("/")
    public ModelAndView index() {
        Map<String, String> model = new HashMap<>();
        model.put("name", "Alexey");
        return new ModelAndView("index", model);
    }
}
```

**resourses/templates/index.html**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
    <body>
        <h1>Welcome to Spring, {{ name }}</h1>
    </body>
</html>
```

**Выдает**

```
Whitelabel Error Page

This application has no explicit mapping for /error, so you are seeing this as a fallback.  
Tue Aug 14 15:30:33 MSK 2018
There was an unexpected error (type=Not Found, status=404).
No message available
```

Если использовать `@RestController`, то всё работает. Есть подозрения на SELinux

Comment: Покажите настройки ViewResolver'a. И что в консоль/лог при этом пишется?

Comment: @JIeIIIa запускаю через Idea в лог ничего не пишет, короме стандартного   `2018-08-15 21:38:32.675  INFO 6124 --- [  restartedMain] s.w.s.m.m.a.RequestMappingHandlerMapping : Mapped "{[/]}" onto public org.springframework.web.servlet.ModelAndView ru.whitearmor.site.controllers.IndexController.index()`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Надо добавить вью резолвер `MustacheViewResolver` для того, чтобы можно было использовать шаблоны с расширением `.html`.

```
@Configuration
public class Config implements WebMvcConfigurer {

  @Bean
  public ViewResolver viewResolver() {
    MustacheViewResolver mustacheViewResolver
        = new MustacheViewResolver();
    mustacheViewResolver.setPrefix("classpath:/templates/");
    mustacheViewResolver.setSuffix(".html");
    mustacheViewResolver.setCache(false);
    return mustacheViewResolver;
  }
}
```

Comment: Использовал, не помогло. Ошибка та же

Comment: Непонятно, все должно работать.

Comment: Да, тожу непонятно, но да ладно, всё равно решил спринг с нуля изучать. Как дойду и пойму где проблема оформлю в качестве ответа :)

Comment: Обновил, если что не работает, пишите.

Comment: А откуда взять классы `ITemplateResolver` и `ClassLoaderTemplateResolver`, у меня их просто нет. Вот сама [статья](https://habr.com/post/333756/)

Comment: Ну да, этого у вас нет, попробуйте вместо этого `MustacheViewResolver`